# Why `<button>` inside `<input type="file" />` won't trigger native file selector, but `<div>` is OK?

Tags: javascript, html

Please see this minimum example

```css
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label for="inputFile">
  <input id="inputFile" class="hidden" type="file" />
  
  <div>Click Me Will Trigger Input Dialog</div>
</label>

<label for="inputFile2">
  <input id="inputFile2" class="hidden" type="file" />
  
  <button>Click Me Won't Trigger Input Dialog</button>
</label>
```

I have two `<input type="file" />` wrapped in `<label />` with explicity specify `id` attribute.

One has `<div />` as a child, the other has `<button />` as a child.

If I click the `<div />`, the native file picker shows up, however, if I click the `<button />`, nothing will happen.

Why is this happening?

Is it possible to use the `<button />` tag but still make the native file picker show up?

Comment: Button has own default function. You can call file input using javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button` has it's own functionality while `div` doesn't. This is why it does not trigger when you click on the `button` (basically the `button` triggers on click, but since it's function doesn't do anything, nothing will happen. Fixable with javascript as well).

However, you could add `pointer-events: none` to that button. It revokes every **mouse event** - and will work just the same as `div` does.

```css
button {
  pointer-events: none;
}

label[for=inputFile2] {
  display: inline-block;
}
label[for=inputFile2]:hover {
  background-color: #333132;
}

label[for=inputFile2] button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

label[for=inputFile2]:hover button {
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label for="inputFile">
  <input id="inputFile" class="hidden" type="file" />
  <div>Click Me Will Trigger Input Dialog</div>
</label>

<label for="inputFile2">
  <input id="inputFile2" class="hidden" type="file" />
  <button>Click Me Won't Trigger Input Dialog</button>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the only way, however, my button has a hover effect, so I might transform my button to `<div />`

Comment: If you want to keep the styling - eg. `:hover` - you have to add it manually to the `label`